# How to close nodewebkit app though server side nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am running webkit from a nodejs script with child_process.exec process

-> server.js

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('nodewebkit', function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
      });
```

The code is inside the directory where nodewebkit 'package.json' and 'index.html' is kept, for running nodewebkit app.

So that when i run

```
node server.js
```

the nodewebkit app should get automatically start.

Now upon some event, i want to close the current nodewebkit app through the same script.

How to do that??

EDIT :

I have tried the following :

```
child.kill(); //not working, does not close the app

require('child_process').exec('kill '+child.pid, function(err){}); //doesn't close the app
```

Comment: `child.kill()` works for me on a Mac.  What system are you on?  Node-webkit does seem to be spawning a couple helper apps, but they all die when I kill the child process, either through `child.kill()` or kill in the shell with the `child.pid` process.